# Google Chart API callback function not getting called

Tags: jquery, google-visualization, donut-chart

I am trying to render data using Google Chart API, but strangely when I load the visualization API, the callback function does not get called.
I have created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/jagzviruz/ZBMnh/

```
var DonutChart = {
data : [
    ['Sales', 20],
    ['Returns', 12],
    ['Pending', 80],
    ['Processed',990]
],
init : function(){
    $.getScript('https://www.google.com/jsapi', this.loadPackages);
},
loadPackages : function(){
    console.log('Loaded API.. now loading packages');
    var o = this;
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(o.renderData);
},
renderData: function(){
    //console.log('Loaded Packages.. Now showing charts');
    alert('Render Data');
}};

DonutChart.init();
```

I never get the alert. Other console messages appear fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DonutChar` rather than `this` to reference the function pointer:

```
$.getScript('https://www.google.com/jsapi', DonutChart.loadPackages);
```

The `init` function is equivalent to:

```
function foo()
  {
  $.getScript('https://www.google.com/jsapi', this.loadPackages);
  }

DonutChart.init = foo
```

As a result, `this` is equal to `foo` rather than `DonutChart`.